# How to validate HTTP request in Laravel

Tags: ios, swift, laravel

I have an iOS application that is making an HTTP request to a server/site that uses Laravel, everything is working fine but I would like to validate the HTTP request before returning any information. Right now the way it works is that you type `example.com/zip-code/51751`and the server responds to the request, what I want, is to make the server respond only to requests coming from the iOS app. What I was thinking is to hard-code a random `key/token` in both my iOS app and in the Laravel app and then include that key as part of my HTTP request, so that I can check the request to see if the key in the request matches the key in the server (`.env` file).

Here is the code I currently have that works fine but doesn't do the validation.

### Routes File

```
Route::get('zip-code/{zipCode}', 'MyController@placeDescription');
```

### Controller

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function placeDescription($zipCode)
    {     
        $placeInfo = InfoDB::where('ZipCode', $zipCode)->get();
        return ($placeInfo);
    }
}
```

### .env File

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:GpyF4XKuxMqCfkylHfdsfFDSjfasdfFDgfsdGfdsFGffhg=
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
...
```

### iOS App / Swift

```
func descriptionForCurrentLocation(zipCode: String, completion:@escaping(_ placeDescription:String?) -> () ){
    
    let siteLink = "http://example.com/zip-code/" + zipCode
    let url = URL(string: siteLink)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        
        guard error == nil else {
            // ERROR
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            // Return, data is empty 
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

        guard let jsonArray = json as? [[String: String]] else {
            // Return, the object returned by the server is not in the right format.
            return
        }

        if jsonArray.isEmpty{
            // Return, array is empty.
            return
        }else{
            let description = jsonArray[0]["CityDescription"]!
            completion(description)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

How can I validate the HTTP request against a random key?

### Edit:

Just for the record here is what I did in my iOS app to add the HTTP header. See `Salman Zafar`s answer for details on how to do the validation in Laravel.

```
    let siteLink = "http://example.com/zip-code/" + zipCode
    let url = URL(string: siteLink)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("161jshghss", forHTTPHeaderField: "CustomKey")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
    ...
```

Comment: Well this can be done any ways if you have user registration then the best way is to use `laravel passport or jwt` and if you don't have it then you can use random key for every ios device if you are registering it if not then you can generate an  `uuid` which you can verify by adding that `uuid` in custom header and then you can validate it

Comment: I do not want to use user authentication, in other words I don't want the users to have to login. The key can be the same for every iOS device it doesn't have to be unique for every device.

Comment: check for headers in hte request, look for the ios identifier

Comment: so just generate a single `uuid` and then add that key in your headers as a custom header and use it for validation

Comment: Well yeah, the validation part is what I'm not sure how to do, where in Laravel do I put the key, how do I check the request?

Comment: @fs_tigre check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a single `uuid` for validating a request and to validate a request you can use below code

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function placeDescription(Request $request, $zipCode)
    { 
       if($request->hasHeader('CustomKey') && $request->header('CustomKey') === "161jshghss")
       {
        $placeInfo = InfoDB::where('ZipCode', $zipCode)->get();
        return ($placeInfo);
       }
       else
       {
         return response(['error' => 'Something is missing'], 403);
       }  
     }
}
```

You have to set `Custom Header` in your `ios` app with the `HeaderName` and `Headervalue` and then you can use the above code.

Thanks.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: Quick question: I don't need to modify the route? `Route::get('zip-code/{zipCode}', 'MyController@placeDescription');`

Comment: @ Salman Zafar - It worked, thanks a lot. Quick question. Do you see a benefit if I add the custom key value (token) to the `.env` file?

Comment: the only benefit will be that you can access that env customkey variable everywhere in your project and also modification will be very easy suppose if you have to change value for some reason then you'll have to change only in .env

Comment: Oh ok, no I was thinking that putting it in the `.env` file was more secured, but I guess that if someone has access to the controller it would also have access to the `.env` file. Thanks.